# Capturar para manusear o controle de media do webview

Tags: android, html5, webview

Como faço para poder saber que a View conforme a imagem foi clicada? Usando o Dump no Eclipse tem o content-desc de control media. Preciso saber quando ele foi clicado para disparar um método.

[image: View controle de mídia]

Comment: Vê se te ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/a/8046523/3257568

Comment: Vou verificar... Porém a imagem é de um webview que roda um vídeo em html5 @Maicon Carraro

Comment: Eu testei mas não funcionou. Não tem como alterar o MediaPlayer de um WebView.